# How can I create JSON text with double quoted values in Delphi?

Tags: json, string, delphi

I want to create this JSON text with Delphi IDE:

```
{
  "uygulamaninAdi": "ZGVuZW1l",
  "uygulamaninSurumu1": "1",
  "uygulamaninSurumu2": "0",
  "uygulamaninSurumu3": "0",
  "uygulamaninSurumu4": "0",
  "uygulamaninMimarisi": "1",
  "calistirilmaDuzeyi": "1",
  "mesajGonderebilmeDurumu": "1",
  "konum": "RDpcUHJvZ3JhbWxhbWE="
}
```

Here are my codes:

```
procedure TfrmManifestDosyasiOlusturucu.btnOluşturClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  jsGönderilecekMesaj := TJSONObject.Create;
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('uygulamaninAdi', TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(edUygulamanınAdı.Text));
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('uygulamaninSurumu1', edUygulamanınSürümü1.Text);
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('uygulamaninSurumu2', edUygulamanınSürümü2.Text);
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('uygulamaninSurumu3', edUygulamanınSürümü3.Text);
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('uygulamaninSurumu4', edUygulamanınSürümü4.Text);
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('uygulamaninMimarisi', IntToStr(cbUygulamanınMimarisi.ItemIndex));
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('calistirilmaDuzeyi', IntToStr(cbÇalıştırılmaDüzeyi.ItemIndex));
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('mesajGonderebilmeDurumu', IntToStr(cbMesajGönderebilmeDurumu.ItemIndex));
  jsGönderilecekMesaj.AddPair('konum', TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(edManifestDosyasınınOluşturulacağıKonum.Text));

  strKomutSatırıParametreleri := '/olustur ' + jsGönderilecekMesaj.ToString;

  ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'bin\Manifest Dosyası Oluşturucu (Yardımcı Uygulama).exe', PWideChar(strKomutSatırıParametreleri), nil, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

But the problem is the Delphi IDE creates this:

```
{uygulamaninAdi:ZGVuZW1l,uygulamaninSurumu1:1,uygulamaninSurumu2:0,uygulamaninSurumu3:0,uygulamaninSurumu4:0,uygulamaninMimarisi:1,calistirilmaDuzeyi:1,mesajGonderebilmeDurumu:1,konum:RDpcUHJvZ3JhbWxhbWE=}
```

As far as I know all of keys should be nested with quotes and all of string values should be nested be quotes.

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`TJSONObject.ToJSON`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONAncestor.ToJSON) instead of `TNSONObject.ToString`.

Also, JSON really isn't well-suited for passing around on the command line. If the target program expects to receive the JSON as a single parameter, and since the JSON has quotes in it and potentially also spaces, you should use `AnsiQuotedStr()` to add quotes around, and to escape quotes inside, of the JSON string.

Comment: I can encode JSON data into Base64 format in order to fix quote issue, then I pass Base64 string to other application. Then, I decode Base64 string and parse JSON data in other application.

Comment: I really would not suggest passing the JSON via the command-line *at all*. Not only is it cumbersome to deal with parsing, but there are also [length restrictions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553) to be aware of, too. Since you seem to be in a position to change the target app, I would suggest either 1) saving the JSON to file and then passing the filename, or 2) establishing a pipe connection between the two apps and send the JSON over that pipe.

Comment: Can I transfer base64 encoded json data through my own uri protocol (for example: stackoverflow://blabla) without character limit?

Comment: Most URL handlers will receive the url over the command-line, but it is possible to receive it through DDE instead. See [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)). Or, you could make the url just contain a server name or pipe name, and then have the target app connect to that server/pipe to transfer the json.

Comment: I have created a DLL file in order to fix my problem. Thank you anyway.